# How to put two ListView in a column?

Tags: flutter

I have two ListView with ExpansionTiles that I would like place one after another inside a column which has some other Widgets first inside it.
This is my code,

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Project Details"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800]),
    body:

    new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Text(project.name, style: new TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.blue[700],
            fontSize: 15.0
        )),
        new RowMaker("District", project.district),
        new RowMaker("River", project.river),
        new RowMaker("Tac Approved", project.tacApproved),
        new RowMaker("Func Sanctioned", project.fundSanctioned),
        new Row(children: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(onPressed: null,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: new Text("Gallery"),
            textColor: Colors.white,),
          new FlatButton(onPressed: null,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: new Text("Upload Images"),
              textColor: Colors.white),
          new FlatButton(
              onPressed: null,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: new Text("Update"),
              textColor: Colors.white),
        ],),
        new ListView(children: getSfListTiles()),
        new ListView(children: getWorkStatementTiles())


    ]
        ,
      )
      ,
    )
);
```

}

Using this, widget body shows blank.If I set ListView directly as body, they show up fine. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try wrapping your `ListView` in `Expanded`. It doesn't have an intrinsic height so you need to give it one.

Comment: How could I wrap the whole body inside a Scrollview ?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question; it depends how much content you have. If it's a lot, consider a CustomScrollView, if it's not much, SingleChildScrollView and change ListView to Column.

Comment: using either CustomScrollView or SingleChildScrollView gives a black background with large text for child widgets.

Comment: the solution I am looking for is that the two ListView (contains ExpansionTile ) to takes up only required space when not expanded but  when expanded it should stretch to its max height  and the problem I am experiencing here is that the two ListView inside the expanded is taking up whole space equally divided and when expanded , they expand within this area.

Comment: The solution that worked in using CustomScrollView, https://gist.github.com/karanvs/44599464f72988b138f5bc783f423b07

Answer (score 21):

You need to provide constrained height to be able to put `ListView` inside `Column`. There are many ways of doing it, I am listing few here.

1. Use `Expanded` for both the list

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: _list1()),
       Expanded(child: _list2()),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Give one `Expanded` and other `SizedBox`

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: _list1()),
       SizedBox(height: 200, child: _list2()),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Use `SizedBox` for both of them.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(height: 200, child: _list1()),
       SizedBox(height: 200, child: _list2()),
     ],
   )
   ```
4. Use `Flexible` and you can change `flex` property in it, just like `Expanded`

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(child: _list1()),
       Flexible(child: _list2()),
     ],
   )
   ```
5. If you `ListView` is short enough to be able to fit in `Column`, use

   ```
   ListView(shrinkWrap: true)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping `ListView` in a fixed size `Container` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

check the link instead listview use sliverlist for better performance

[Tuturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0)  and
[full Example](https://dartpad.dev/workshops.html?webserver=https://fdr-shrinkwrap-slivers.web.app)

```
 return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text("List 1 item${index}")),
                  childCount: 5,
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text("List 2 item${index}")),
                  childCount: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```